# How to draw a line from one element to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a tree like structure. I have created the numbers in a circle using html badges. Now I want to draw lines from one element to another element. I have tried using an image which is like left diagonal and right diagonal. But it is not working.

This is my html for creating Badges:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<span id="0" class="cl w3-badge">0</span><br><br><br><br>
<span id="1" class="cl w3-badge">0</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span id="2" class="cl w3-badge">0</span>
```

This is my javascript:

```
var data = [];
data.push(5);
data.push(6);
data.push(4);
$('.w3-badge').each(function(i, obj) {
 document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = data[i];
});
```

[This is image of left line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CJtE.png)

Can someone help me??

I'm trying to get my final tree to be like this:
[Final tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCFNw.png)

Comment: First of all, don't use `&nbsp;` and `<br>` for spacing; that's what CSS is for. You'll want to look into using [the canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

using svg is the best option for those kind of thing,
i wrote a function below that do exactly what you need.
you have tho to rewrite it to your needs.
use full page to see the result right.

```js
function drawLine(div1, div2){
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
 svgPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
var div1Offset = div1[0].getBoundingClientRect();
var div2Offset = div2[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            var pathNr = "";
            pathNr = "M"+ (div1Offset.width + div1Offset.left)+ " " +  ((div1Offset.top + div1Offset.height) / 2)
            pathNr += "h" +( div2Offset.left)
            pathNr += "v" +(div2Offset.top)
            pathNr += "h" +( -div2Offset.left )
            svgPath.setAttribute("d", pathNr);
            svgPath.setAttribute("stroke", "red");
            svgPath.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1");
            svgPath.setAttribute("fill", "white");
            svgPath.setAttribute("id", "test");
            svg.appendChild(svgPath);
            $("body").append(svg);

}

$(document).ready(function(){

drawLine($(".box_1"), $(".box_2"))

});
```

```css
.box{
width:150px;
height:150px;
margin:30px;
background:black;

}

svg{
position:absolute;
left:0; top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box box_1'></div>


<div class='box box_2'></div>
```